# Десериализация в нужный класс объекта в сложном классе

Tags: android, сериализация, unserialize

Осваиваю программирование. Пишу игруху. Сохраняю статус игры сериализацией класса. (Gson от гугла).

```
class Town {
     ArrayList<Location> locs;
     ArrayList<Body> bodys;
}
class Body {
      ...
}
class Boss extends Body{
      ...
}
```

***bodys*** - содержит список ссылок на **Body** и на **Boss**. Просматривая весь список выборку нужного класса делаю по условию:

`if (town.getBodys instanceof Boss){
     ...
 }`

Сериализую класс **Town** и сохраняю в файл. После, при десериализации класса **Town**, объект **Boss** из ArrayList десериализован в класс **Body** :-(

Подскажите как-то можно его привести в Boss после десериализации?

Сериализую так:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
Gson gson = builder.create();
fileWriter.write(gson.toJson(town));
```

Десериализую так:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
Gson gson = builder.create();
town = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(getFilesDir() + "/" + nameTown + ".dat"), Town.class);
```

Comment: А как вы десериализуете? Можно было весь имеющийся код не прикреплять, а код десериализации прикрепить.

Comment: мне кажется, что тут код самого класса нужен, т.к. там ArrayList <Body> и при серелизации "теряется" наследник, но не уверен, возможно нужно просто какую-то аннотацию добавить

Comment: В json-строке нет никакой информации о типах объектов - поэтому при десериализации типы берутся из переданного в метод `Town.class`, а в нём указано: ArrayList< **Body** >. Тут нужно делать кастомный десериализатор или адаптер типов. На en-SO есть решения по этому вопросу: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19588020

Comment: спасибо, по ссылке пока слишком сложно для моего уровня, пришлось выделить для каждого расширенного класса свой ArrayList :)